# How would you counter an email/honeypot mischief scenario?

Tags: email, attack-prevention, denial-of-service, honeypot

I'm thinking through a mischief denial-of-service scenario that seems too easy to employ.

Your web-site validates email addresses for new users on sign-up.

1. A rogue party (a competitor) performs sign-ups using honeypot email addresses.
2. Your server sends its confirmation emails to the honeypot addresses.
3. Your server gets marked as a spammer, then none of your emails go though. **(Denial of service.)**

How do you counter this?

If a list of honeypot emails is available, the spammers would use it.

Is there a way even to detect this?  Do gmail or vendors in this realm have ways you can check your domain, or appeal?

Others asking about being mis-identified as spammers are asking about [bulk sending](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72550/gmail-is-blocking-my-emails-sent-to-them), not relevant. (There's a reference to `openspf.org` "Sender Policy Framework" but that site's dead.)

Comment: Of course you can appeal a reputation score from phish pots. This is a core function of their services. Have you looked up a phish/spam pot to see how they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [list bombing](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/237400/42391). **If your server is facilitating a list bomb, that is indeed *your* fault.**

Put safeguards on your website to avoid abuse. For example, no single IP should be able to input too many emails in a certain amount of time (though you do have to consider [larger NATs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT)). Consider increasingly difficult captchas to correspond to increasing volume matching an IP (or a tight CIDR) plus a hard cutoff that prevents a higher threshold of subscriptions per hour.

Regarding the old [OpenSPF​.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20190225203208/https://openspf.org/) site: [Sender Policy Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) (SPF) won't help you here, it's an unrelated technology that, with [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC), can prevent spoofing. List bombs aren't spoofed.

Comment: Accepting this for the here expertise and for putting me on the right track. Thanks!

@schroeder 's comment also was key in finding mistaken listings appeal pages https://www.projecthoneypot.org/contact_us.php?ft=Mistaken Listing.

Many thanks to you both.